# What to do about Eclipse's “No repository found containing: …” error messages when install?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, m2eclipse

Previously i am successfully download and install eclipse from eclipse installer,But unfortunately deleted eclipse folder.Now i try again to install same eclipse installer but that time display error meaasge:

```
[2016-03-02 11:45:26] Executing bootstrap tasks
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.jee.mars
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2199, branch=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81, commit=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2199, branch=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81, commit=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2199, branch=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81, commit=7194e06d06a87ced95779121a8281b59b9abdf81
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Mars))
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Offline = false
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Mirrors = true
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Resolving 6 requirements from 3 repositories to /home/ubuntu/jee-mars2/eclipse
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement epp.package.jee [4.5.0,4.6.0)
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0)
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0)
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [3.11.0,3.12.0)
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement org.eclipse.pde.feature.group [3.11.0,3.12.0)
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201602261000
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
    [2016-03-02 11:45:26] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1200 Artifact not found: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/content.xml.xz.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/content.xml.xz
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryStatusHelper.checkFileNotFound(RepositoryStatusHelper.java:297)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.checkException(FileReader.java:478)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:435)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:358)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:101)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:175)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:235)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:402)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:339)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:146)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:389)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1468)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
      at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1):

Help>Install new software>Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

Eclipse will prompt that the content isn't authorized or something like that. just ignore and continue. then everything will be OK.

At least this trick resolved my problems similar like this

Comment: I am not updating eclipse.I try to install eclipse.

Comment: try this:cmd>eclipse.exe-clean. This cleans up the installation of eclipse and helps it to run\

Comment: you have deleted the eclipse folder. so first unistall the eclipse and then try to reinstall it with the eclipse instaler.if not works install eclipse with different version

Comment: I have done this solution,but not solve my problem.I am occurring same problem.